# Applescript: Toggle Alfred

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to toggle Alfred through Keyboard Maestro by writing some Applescript. Here is the code right now I am using but not working for deactivating Alfred window since it looks like the Alfred is not activated as a window.

```
set appName to "Alfred 3"
set is_start to false

tell application "System Events"
    if not (exists process appName) then
        set is_start to true
    else
        if visible of process appName then
            set visible of process appName to false
        else
            set frontmost of process appName to true
        end if
    end if
end tell

tell application "Alfred 3"
    reopen -- open a default window if there are no open windows
    activate -- make frontmost
end tell
```

Need some help to find a solution...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: Alfred and Keyboard Maestro overlap in functionality and it may be sufficient to use one *or* the other.</sup>

Programmatically, Alfred only offers *activation*, not *deactivation*:

```applescript
 tell application "Alfred 3" to search # activates Alfred
```

You can only achieve *deactivation* by sending the global hotkey that is configured in Alfred itself for toggling its activation *while Alfred is active*; by default, that hotkey is <kbd>⌥Space</kbd>
:

```applescript
 tell application "System Events" to keystroke " " using {option down}
```

Thus, given that Alfred's own hotkey is a *toggle*, all you need to do is:

```applescript
 tell application "System Events" to keystroke " " using {option down}
```

**Caveat**: If the Keyboard Maestro shortcut you use to invoke this AppleScript contains modifiers *other* than the one involved in toggling Alfred, this won't work.